# ConfigurationManager.GetSection does not inherit from System.Configuration.IConfigurationSectionHandler

Tags: c#, .net, .net-standard-2.0

in a project .netstandard 2.0 I receive this exception

> System.Configuration.ConfigurationErrorsException: 'An error occurred
> creating the configuration section handler for mySection: Type
> 'Custom.Config.Configurator' does not inherit from
> 'System.Configuration.IConfigurationSectionHandler'.

when I use

```
System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.GetSection("mySection");
```

The section is the following

```
<section name="mySection" type="Custom.Config.Configurator, Custom" />
```

It seems the System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager doesn't work as I expected, before the project was in .NET framework and it worked. I installed System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager 6.0.0.0 and the IConfigurationSectionHandler is implemented.

Comment: It seems you have a `Custom.Config.Configurator`, correct? Can you post that class too?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After troubling two days I put the code of `System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.GetSection("mySection");` in .NET framework project.

Likely System.Configuration and System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager don't work together very well